# Bitrix Мультисайтовость

Tags: битрикс

Делаю  на одном хостинге, под разными доменными именами. Главный сайт установлен и давно работает. На хостинге создал новую директорию, привязал к ней домен. Сделал симлинки, перекинул access.php.
Проблема следующего характера - не запускается визард после создания второго сайта в админке. Пустой экран без каких-либо ошибок. В директории сайта создаётся index.php следующего содержания :

```
<?
            define("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED", true);
            define("WIZARD_DEFAULT_SITE_ID", "c1");
            define("WIZARD_DEFAULT_TONLY", true);
            define("PRE_LANGUAGE_ID","ru");
            define("PRE_INSTALL_CHARSET","windows-1251");
            include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/install/wizard/wizard.php");
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема оказалась в символьных ссылках, я использовал шаблон site1/bitrix и site2/bitrix при таком схеме ссылка появлялись,через фтп осуществлялся переход, но битрикс с ними не работал, указал полный путь server/user/site1/bitrix и битрик съел и всё заработало.